# Sort specific columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (the sample looks like this)

```
Type          SKU      Description   FullDescription        Size      Price
Variable       2        Boots          Shoes on sale       XL,M,S       
Variation      2.5      Boots XL                             XL       330
Variation      2.6      Boots M                              M        330
Variation      2.7      Boots S                              S        330
Variable       3        Boots           Helmet Sizes      E42,E41
Variation      3.8      Helmet E42                          E42       89
Variation      3.2      Helmet E41                          E41       89
```

What I want to do is sort the values based on Size so the final data frame should look like this:

```
  Type          SKU      Description   FullDescription        Size      Price
    Variable       2        Boots          Shoes on sale       S,M,XL        
    Variation      2.7      Boots S                             S       330
    Variation      2.6      Boots M                             M        330
    Variation      2.5      Boots XL                            XL        330
    Variable       3        Boots           Helmet Sizes       E41,E42
    Variation      3.2      Helmet E41                          E41       89
    Variation      3.8      Helmet E42                          E42       89
```

I can just use `sort_values()` but I can't seem to find anything to retain the order of Type and SKU. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the logic sort by the size .

Comment: How is `XL` followed by `M` and `S` in your rows second to fourth? Where your last 2 rows are sorted like `E41` and `E42`?

Comment: Are you trying to change individual records? or trying to change the way the records are ordered within the dataframe?  From your  example, it looks like you're trying to change the pairings of Description with Size, so that "Boots S" are Size "XL". Did you mean to switch E41,E42 for E42,E41 in the "Boots Helmet Sizes" row? Do you need a custom sort function for the Size column or is usual alphabetic sorting sufficient?  Please fix all typos, include your actual sort_values() call, the output of sort_values(), and detail what's wrong with that output.

Comment: I AM really sorry not sure how it posted the previous unedited version, I have edited the question again with the correct dataframe needed and it will help understand the question clearly. Really sorry again

Comment: @BENY can you re-open ? i have an answer that will work

Comment: @Manakin feel free to answer it , it now opened

Answer (score 1):

A little bit long

```
out = df.groupby(df.Type.eq('Variable').cumsum()).\
       apply(lambda x : pd.concat([x.iloc[[0]].assign(Size=lambda y : y['Size'].str.split(',').str[::-1].str.join(',')),
                        x.iloc[1:,].iloc[::-1]]))
Out[458]: 
             Type  SKU Description     Size  Price
Type                                              
1    0   Variable  2.0       Boots   S,M,XL    NaN
     3  Variation  2.7      BootsS        S  330.0
     2  Variation  2.6      BootsM        M  330.0
     1  Variation  2.5     BootsXL       XL  330.0
2    4   Variable  3.0       Boots  E41,E42    NaN
     6  Variation  3.2   HelmetE41      E41   89.0
     5  Variation  3.8   HelmetE42      E42   89.0
```

Comment: nice one, i made my answer for his original df, but the new one has to many lines of code so i think yours is nicer

Comment: No idea why it's not working on my original dataset, it is showing variables below the variations and the order is still not sorted

Comment: It works fine but just in reverse order. Variable 2 is below variations 2.7,2.6,2.5 and Size for variable is XL,M,S. And for type it is supposed to show indexes but in my original dataset it is showing 0 in the whole column